# New Windows Phone 8 app fails to compile - missing assembly XamlServicesWP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have recently installed the Windows Phone 8 SDK on my machine. I tried creating a new  Windows Phone Silverlight application but it always fails to build.
This is the error I am getting:

> The "CompileXaml" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'XamlServicesWP, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'XamlServicesWP,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

When I installed the SDK it finished with a warning saying that the event log file is full, though I really doubt this is the issue.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on Windows 8.1.

Is this a known issue?

Thanks!

Comment: is your project open elsewhere? Like in Blend?

Comment: No, but I ended up solving it, take a look at the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 solved my problem. Somehow VS 2013 was taking wrong MSBuild version.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it.

What happened was that I started by (accidentally) installing SDK for WP8.1, and then I removed it. For some reason, that seemed to be the problem - when I reinstalled it the problem went away.

Don't know what's the cause, but this is probably an MS bug.